# Unity Scaling rect transform left right and scale x

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having a problem in resizing a UI panel in unity on button click. I enter a negative value on the left but after I run it it doesn't read the "-" value and I also want to scale the size of the panel to 1.24 here is a picture of its default state, after I execute the code and what I want it to be like.
I'm sorry cause its hard for me to explain it in words so I just compile it in one picture.

PS. I've searched for codes that can resize the scale of the Rect but the Rect just disappear.[image]

```
//Scaling left and right of the panel
        DescriptionPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().offsetMax = new Vector2(-91.375f, -1);
        DescriptionPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().offsetMin = new Vector2(76.295f, 0);

        //Scaling x-axis of the panel when I include it in runtime my panel disappear so I did not include it in the picture below.
        DescriptionPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.24f, 1f);
```

UPDATE - Ive already fixed the Left and Right RectTransform problem.
The remaining problem is resizing the scale of the rectTransform.
When I execute this code my Panel disappears. I need to set the X axis to 1.24.

```
 DescriptionPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().transform.localScale = new Vector2(1.24f, 1f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to use Vector3 when transforming a localscale, because Your DescriptionPanel might be moved over behind the canvas